# MIT Scheme message passing list boolean

Tags: list, scheme, message

I've been wracking my brain on a scheme problem for the last couple days that involves creating a procedure with message passing that keeps track of a list of friends, and can then manipulate that list to change the value of a specific friend to online or offline. If the person that is put in is a friend, it returns true. If they haven't been added yet, it returns false. It can also show the list of friends that are online, and another list of the ones that you have. Basically, the idea is to make something of a changeable Facebook tracker. It responds to 4 inputs: 'add, 'toggle-status, 'get-online-friends, and 'get-friends.

This is what I've managed to get so far:

```
(define (sort-strings lst)
    (sort lst string<?))

(define (make-facebook-list)
(let ((T '()))
(define (dispatch x)
  (define (add-person name)
(set! T (cons (cons name #f) T)) 
'done)
  (define (online? friend)
(eq? friend #t))
  (define (toggle-status! name)
(begin ;(if () (set! T (cons (cons name #t) T)))
  (if (member name T)
      (set-cdr! T (cons (cons name (not (cdr name)) T))))
  (if (member name T) #t #f)))
  (define (get-online-friends!)
(sort-strings (filter online? T)))
  (define (get-friends!)
(sort-strings T))
  (cond ((eq? x 'add) add-person)
    ((eq? x 'toggle-status) toggle-status!)
    ((eq? x 'get-online-friends) (get-online-friends!))
    ((eq? x 'get-friends) (get-friends!))
    (else (error "Unknown Request" x))))
dispatch))
```

And these are the test cases that I'm using:

```
(define my-lst (make-facebook-list))
(display ((my-lst 'add) "Francis"))(newline) ; should return 'done
(display ((my-lst 'add) "Adrian"))(newline) ; should return 'done
(display ((my-lst 'add) "Zule"))(newline) ;  should return 'done
(display ((my-lst 'add) "Geralt"))(newline) ; should return 'done
(display ((my-lst 'add) "Dexter"))(newline) ; should return 'done
(display ((my-lst 'add) "Leonidas"))(newline) ; should return 'done
(display ((my-lst 'toggle-status) "Leonidas"))(newline) ; should return #t
(display ((my-lst 'toggle-status) "Francis"))(newline) ; should return #t
(display ((my-lst 'toggle-status) "Zule"))(newline) ; should return #t
(display ((my-lst 'toggle-status) "Xavier"))(newline) ; should return #f
(display (my-lst 'get-online-friends))(newline) ; should return ("Francis" "Leonidas" "Zule")
(display (my-lst 'get-friends)) ; should return ("Adrian" "Dexter" "Francis" "Geralt" "Leonidas" "Zule")
```

I know that they won't all work right now, which is why I commented out some of the procedures. The one I'm trying to get to run correctly is the the procedure that toggles the status to online or offline. I've been led to believe that "member" is used to check if a certain value is a part of a list.A m I going about this the wrong way?

NOTE: the sort-strings procedure is meant to be used with the procedures that return a list of friends, so as to keep them in alphabetical order.

Comment: I changed the phrasing of the original problem. I also decided to use ifs instead of conds since I felt that the layout was more appropriate for this type of problem.

Comment: I do not agree with you :). Your code became less readable IMHO. Nested `if`’s are the same as a `cond`-expression and you could also do some more abstractions. I also think there are some misconceptions with respect to `eq?` and `equal?` in your code. I will add a suggestion for `make-facebook-list` to my answer.

Comment: You caught me! The truth is, I have an easier time understanding the simpler syntax of the if rather than the cond just because in the past problems I've done, I've become more familiar with the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is `begin`, which forces the following expressions to be evaluated sequentially:

```
(define (make-facebook-list)
  (define T '())
  (define (dispatch x)
    (lambda (fl)
      (cond ((eq? x 'add) 
             (begin
               (set! T (append T (list fl)))
               'done))
            (else 'invalid))))
  dispatch)

scheme@(guile-user)> (define my-lst (make-facebook-list))
scheme@(guile-user)> ((my-lst 'add) "Francis")
$1 = done
```

**Edit**

```
(define (make-facebook-account)
  (let ((*facebook-friends* '()))
    (define (sort-alphabetically sequence)
      (sort-list sequence string<?))
    (define (friend name)
      (assoc name *facebook-friends*))
    (define (friends-name friend)
      (car friend))
    (define (friends-status friend)
      (cdr friend))
    (define (online? friend)
      (eq? (friends-status friend) #t))
    (define (friend-on-facebook? name)
      (if (member (friend name)
                  *facebook-friends*)
          #t #f))
    (define (add-person! name)
      (begin
        (set! *facebook-friends*
              (cons (cons name #f)
                    *facebook-friends*))
        'done))
    (define (toggle-status! name)
      (if (friend-on-facebook? name)
          (begin
           (set-cdr! (friend name)
                      (if (online? (friend name))
                          #f #t))
           'done)
          (error
           "Person no friend on facebook -- TOGGLE-STATUS!" name)))
    (define (get-friends table)
      (sort-alphabetically
       (map friends-name table)))
    (define (get-online-friends table)
      (get-friends
       (filter online? table)))
    (define (dispatch m)
      (cond ((eq? m 'add!) add-person!)
            ((eq? m 'toggle-status!) toggle-status!)
            ((eq? m 'get-friends)
             (get-friends *facebook-friends*))
            ((eq? m 'get-online-friends)
             (get-online-friends *facebook-friends*))
            ((eq? m 'friend-on-facebook?) friend-on-facebook?)
            (else
             (error "Unknown request -- DISPATCH" m))))
    dispatch))
```

Comment: Thank you, Ludwig. I had forgotten about begin.

Comment: Just a quick question: when it comes to returning the (sorted) list of friends, would I basically just return the table?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ludwig. You've really been a big help. There's just one thing that's throwing me off a bit: the list of friends I meant was the one where it's all of the friends that you have. The list of friends that are online wouldn't just be a call to the table (with sort-strings in front of it), wouldn't it?

Comment: I implemented your facebook-tracker completely by using a an association-list consisting of pairs, e.g. `'((name-1 . status-1) (name-2 . status-2))`. Toggling the status of a person makes use of `set-cdr!`. Have fun studying the code. :)

Comment: I'm curious: how would the code work without the assoc function? In my assignment, it doesn't call for the code to be done like that. I can't add the status of a name with the name in the same add-person! procedure. What I'm trying to do is have all the heavy work (changing from online to offline or offline to online, returning true if they're a friend and false if they haven't been added, and having the name automatically start off with a false value) be done within the 'toggle-status procedure.

Comment: Some comments: 1) You are essentially doing the same as I did and constructing an alist. So why get rid of `assoc`? You are giving up data abstraction (`friend`, `friends-name`, `friends-status`). SICP ch. 2!  Your `online?`-predicate becomes senseless because nobody knows what `friend` is and why he should be true. 2) I have changed `add-person!` in my answer to start with `#f` by default. 3) Your `toggle-status!` won’t work, it is a mess (3 arguments to cons, what is the meaning of `(not (cdr name))`?, relation of `if`-expr. unclear) 4) Compare also my updated version of `toggle-status!`.

Comment: Ok, now I feel like an idiot for having made those mistakes -_-

I got it working like I need to now, and I have to admit, your method makes a lot more sense than mine. Thanks again, Ludwig.